# How to parse strange json

Tags: android, json, sqlite, search

I have a project which requires the json objects to be saved in database and then based on the users action will display info.

I can get the json from the API using here:http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/ but need help with parsing the following  which is a part of json objects.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem! What do you want to do and where is the problem? Seems you fetched some JSON data and presented them in a list. Why do you need sqlite for searching? You could simply search your ListAdapter data...

Comment: Rodja,Here is my problem I need to allow the users to search my app and based on that search display rental properties as listview using API.So far I can display the location response into my app but not really what I need.How do I approach this,I can show you the API i'm using.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your data structure and amount of entries.  If amount is small and queries / sorting requirements are simple, you may just bypass database  entirely and parse JSON with buil it (not so good solution in terman of memory consumption) or pull parser ( like GSON  - small external dependency bu way better perfromance )

Another option would be just store JSON documents in database,  and some fields  from them as separate columns for querying and indexing.

If you like to have complex object hierarchy you will find that you are reimplementing 
some ORM solution.